# Retrieve fields schema in Visual Studio of stored procedure which uses temp tables

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have some complex stored procedures pulling data from other databases using linked servers. This data is put into temp tables which are joined in a select query for output. The procedures work fine but in visual studio if I try to add the stored procedure to a dataset using the designer I get the error invalid object name #tmp or whatever the first temp table is called. It is unable to retrieve the database schema. It's the same for using and sqldatasource in ASP.NET.

The procedure is still usable but I have to manually add all the columns it should output to the datatable. This is going to be a pain to do manually and I assume it is to do with the way visual studio gathers the output fields from the stored procedure, it doesn't seem to run it in the normal way. Is there a way to correct this as I have quite a lot of these to do and don't want to have to add all the columns manually, which is time consuming and error prone.

Comment: Is there a reason you can not use a table-value function instead of a stored procedure?

Comment: Yeah you can't use dynamic SQL or openquery in a function as far as I know. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Answered my own question after much more research. There is a bizarre solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After googling for a while I found a bizarre solution putting:

```
IF 1=0 BEGIN
SET FMTONLY OFF
END
```

At the start of your stored procedure allows the designer to correctly get the schema information. This code obviously never runs but it solves the issue. FMTONLY is related to only returning meta data about a stored procedure. I am using sql server 2005.

Comment: WARNING!  Be aware that when you do this, the stored procedure will actually be fully executed and committed every time the Visual Studio designer checks it.  If you have any update/delete/insert statements in your proc, they will be run.  Only use this on procedures that return data only.  Otherwise, this is an excellent find!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

SET FMTONLY OFF

I Dont know why someone put in IF 1=0 in the other post? I think it was just to prove that when FMTONLY is ON that all conditions in IF / ELSE Statements are executed!

FMTONLY is typically turned on by applications such as SSRS and Visual Studio when refreshing the schema information for a stp. With FMTONLY on no statements are executed only the column names are returned. The issue is that because no statements are executed the temp table does not get created, and therefore the columns returned by any select statements on the temp table are unknown.

Setting FMTONLY ON will cause the stp to run fully. IF you have any insert / update / delete statements in your stp they will run, so capture the state of FMTONLY before you turn it OFF and take appropriate measures to prevent updates.

You can determine if FMTONLY is on by checking if 1 = 0. If it does then FMTONLY is on and you could just run a simple select of the columns that your stp normally returns.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it cannot read metadata is because you have a #Temp table and it cannot find the temp table. You can try to get around it by defining the metadata using a `TOP 0` query

```
SELECT TOP 0
    CONVERT (NULL, VarChar (30)) AS Column1,
    CONVERT (NULL, INTEGER) AS Column2,
    CONVERT (NULL, DECIMAL (9, 2)) AS Column3,
    CONVERT (NULL, VarChar (55)) AS Column4

UNION

SELECT *
FROM #MyTempTable
```

Comment: Semes like that will take nearly as long, I don't see why visual studio can't obtain the meta data by running the query as normal since for instance Crystal report can do this without hassle.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot obtain meta data here is because it could depend on data.  For example.

```
If Exists(Select 1 From Table Where Column1 = 7)
  Select Col1, Col2 From Table2
Else
  Select Col3, Col4, Col5 From Table2
```

I would never write a stored procedure that has a different number of columns depending on data, BUT it is possible to do.  Just for a moment, suppose you had a stored procedure like this.  What column list should be returned?

Comment: Yeah I understand that and I would also never write one where it would return potentially a different number of columns. But why doesn't it just retrieve the columns for the variables I specify.

Comment: Because it still may not be deterministic.  Also consider that a stored procedure could return no recordset, one recordset, or even multiple recordsets.

You can also use random number functions so that each call returns different columns.

Comment: Yeah but it's only being used for the designer, the developer knows what columns need to exist in the end it's just quicker for it to put them in for you based on the values you give it for the stored proc. An example is crystal report it takes the values you give it and pulls out the last datatable a stored procedure gives you. It doesn't matter the fact that they may not exist at runtime as this is always the case anyway as you could easily change any sql query.