# DataSet.xsd cannot list column from stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dataset

I have a project using ASP.Net MVC 3 and now I'm creating a report for my project. I have several reports in my project and all of them are using stored procedures. For creating a report in MVC 3, first I create a new dataset. I have trouble with one of my reports. I have a procedure like this (named `SP_Rpt`) :

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_batch (batch_id VARCHAR(20))  
EXEC SP_StrListToTable @batchId, ',', #temp_batch

select Batch_Id, Batch_Date
from Batch 
where Batch_Id in (select * from #temp_batch)
and isnull(Payment_Decline_Date,'') = '' and Payment_Amount > 0
and Batch_Open = 0 and Invoice_Paid_Amt > 0
```

when I try to add new table adapter using `SP_Rpt` I get this error:

> The wizard detected the following problems when configuring the TableAdapter: "SP_Rpt"
>
> Details:
>
> Generate SELECT statement invalid object name '#temp_batch'
>
> To add These components to your dataset, click Finish.

I click finish and there's no column in my table adapter. But I can to preview data. And when I create Report and choose that dataset, I don't have any column (I can't design new report). Is there something wrong with my procedure (I don't think so, because I can preview data) ? How to list column in my data set using that stored procedure ?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the following at the beginning of the stored procedure:

```
IF 1=0 BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF
END
```

[Retrieve fields schema in Visual Studio of stored procedure which uses temp tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888081/retrieve-fields-schema-in-visual-studio-of-stored-procedure-which-uses-temp-tabl)

Comment: IF 1=0 BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF
END
CREATE TABLE #temp_batch (batch_id VARCHAR(20))  
EXEC SP_StrListToTable @batchId, ',', #temp_batch

select Batch_Id, Batch_Date
from Batch 
where Batch_Id in (select * from #temp_batch)
and isnull(Payment_Decline_Date,'') = '' and Payment_Amount > 0
and Batch_Open = 0 and Invoice_Paid_Amt > 0
so you mean like that ?

Comment: yes, as the very first statement after `BEGIN` in the stored procedure, then you'll have to rebind dataset